# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/calm-forest-38557.git'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

```
 "name": "newapp",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
       "start": "nodemon server.js",
      "start-server": "nodemon server.js",
      "start-client": "npm start --prefix my-app",
      "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-server\" \"npm run start-client\"",
      "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix my-app && npm run build  
                           --prefix my-app"
```

when i want to push heroku this mern app i can't build the file in react app and also whwn i use

```
"heroku-postbuild":"cd my-app && npm install && npm run build "
```

the error is different which is:-

```
 [enter image description here][1]"msg":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/my-app/build/index.html'"
```

this is photo of my folder list[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xGGT.png

the logs of heroku
> Build
Running heroku-postbuild

```
   > newapp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_a1510cbf93d0f6e7800b0118461ed11e
   >  npm install --prefix my-app && npm run build --prefix my-app
   
   up to date in 0.489s
   found 0 vulnerabilities
   
 npm ERR! code ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall open
  npm ERR! path /tmp/build_a1510cbf93d0f6e7800b0118461ed11e/my- 
    app/package.json
  npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    '/tmp/build_a1510cbf93d0f6e7800b0118461ed11e/my-app/package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent 
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.DC8r1/_logs/2020-06-29T08_36_42_692Z-debug.log
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 254
   npm ERR! newapp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: ` npm install --prefix my-app && 
 npm run build --prefix my-app`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the newapp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.DC8r1/_logs/2020-06-29T08_36_42_707Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
     - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node- 
 js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

Comment: first try fix this error `Node version not specified in package.json` by adding `"engines": { "node": "13.x" }` to package.json

Comment: but it also don't work